# Jenkins Pipeline exiting when grep command of shell script fails

Tags: bash, jenkins, grep, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have a Jenkinsfile written for Scripted Pipeline where I have the following piece of code:

```
sh """ cd $WORRKSPACE
       source myscript.sh
       cd \${EXPORTED_VAR1}
       .
       .
       .
"""
```

So I source myscript which in turn has a source command in it, say `source their_script.sh` . The problem is like their_script.sh contains a line `echo $0 | egrep -iqe string`. And whenever egrep finds no match my Jenkins job exits. But this happened suddenly and it was working till yesterday!!!

I understand that grep returns status 1 when it finds no match and that is why it exits. But I wanted myscript to continue even if grep failed. I also understand that using `set +e` and `set -e` will help me not to exit if grep fails. But I am not allowed to modify their_script.sh. If I add `set +/-e` when I call myscript itself, will the case be like none of the errors will exit the script? Wont it ignore all errors from exiting?

Is there any solution so that I can continue with my job even if grep fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
sh """#!/bin/bash -xe
cd ${WORKSPACE}
## etc.
...
"""
```

Comment: Adding #!/bin/bash at the beginning worked. I didnt add -xe as I want it to be exited on error.

Comment: But may I know what difference does adding /bin/bash makes. Already myscript contains /bin/bash

Comment: should it be possible to use also something like the following, to save the state in a jenkins var? `TRIGGER_THE_PIPELINE = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 |tail -1 |grep "JK#" ')`